# React preboot, recording server side events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

[Angular 2 has the nifty feature](https://github.com/jeffwhelpley/preboot), where when you render something on the server, Angular will attach event listeners to capture the user events that occur before your client side application is rendered.

Is there any way to do this with React?

Right now, for instance, if you're using server side rendering with React, and your server responds with an `<input>` tag, currently whatever the user types into that input field won't be captured in the `onChange` event handler.  Instead, when the client is rendered, the `<input>` tag will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

React should be used only as a function to display data. 
Your input should have state in store.

If you want to render the value on the server you should have the value in server store during the rendering.

Angular solution of recreating events is not as optimal as just rendering data from single store as react and flux pattern promote.

Answer (score -1):

Saying

> before your client side application is rendered

is a little bit confusing because the application is primarily rendered server-side.

There is a delay between the moment the HTML being displayed and the moment your javascript application be bootstrapped client side. This is always true as long as the javascript is loaded in separated files and required time to the browser to be executed.

You refer to the [angular/preboot](https://github.com/angular/preboot) repo which allows us to record all the client events fired before the Javascript application being bootstrapped, and replay them after.

Everything is explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wvZ7gakqV4).
[image]

[angular/preboot](https://github.com/angular/preboot) works with any front end JavaScript framework (i.e. React, Vue, Ember, etc.)

Comment: I really don't know why I am getting a -1 here.
I probably can improve my answer in many ways, feedback welcome :)